# question about installing a new electrical breaker panel

Tags: electrical

I am installing a new 100 amp load center and it must be installed with AFCI and GFCI breakers. do I need to remove existing GFI receptacles.

Comment: Don't have to remove the receptacles, just need to remember to reset breaker and receptacle.  I would check to see if you need the combo breakers, instead of just AFCI breakers if you already have GFCI receptacles. AFCI/GFCI breakers might just be a blanket requirement for new panels/new houses.

Comment: What jurisdiction? Is the panel a straight replacement (i.e., replacing older/obsolete/smaller panel(s) in roughly the same location) or is it truly new (e.g., moving panel from one side of the house to the other)?

Answer (score 2):

You are incorrect about GFCI breakers.  GFCIs come in many varieties, and nothing in the code specifies a GFCI breaker *specifically*.  So if the existing GFCI deadfronts, switches, combos and receptacles you now have installed sufficiently satisfy the GFCI requirement, then you don't need a GFCI breaker.

On AFCIs, yeah it needs to be a breaker for all practical purposes. It can only be at the first receptacle if the run to that first receptacle is a) in metal conduit or b) entirely buried in 2" of concrete. So "nope" for most people.  If you are using metal conduit, then congrats! You just saved $30 a circuit.

I myself run a short EMT conduit to a steel box right next to the panel, and stick AFCI or GFCI receptacles or deadfronts there.  I'm cheap lol. I use 4-11/16" square boxes to mount 2 at a time, but I get those at an electrical supply, I don't pay $7 each at the box stores. I have Pushmatic panels (excellent but out of production; no AFCIs offered).

Also if this is *merely a panel replacement*, and not any sort of new work, you should be grandfathered as far as AFCI/GFCI replacement.

Note that a "100A panel" is a bit small for a lot of work.  The key thing in selecting a panel is **plenty of breaker spaces** - more than you'll ever imagine you could use. Breaker spaces are cheap, and people's imaginations are extremely feeble when thinking about future requirements. Certainly any house (i.e. full house) should have 40 breaker spaces.

You will find larger panels only exist in 200A rating. If you were buying car tires and found the PERFECT tires for you, except they said "130 mph rating", would you say "Oh no, I can't use these, I don't drive 130 mph!" LOL of course not, you'd actually feel safer knowing they're rated for higher speeds. Well, it's exactly the same with panel bus rating amps.

Now a main panel's main breaker needs to be exactly correct for the service. But you can buy 100A breakers for main panels.

In fact if you are thinking about a generator, ever, you could use a large Siemens *main lug* panel, and get a 100A and 30A *normal* breaker, and a $30 ECSBPK01 interlock. The 100 is your utility breaker and the 30 is your generator breaker. On a 40-space Siemens that'll still leave 36 spaces for the house. Siemens makes tandem AFCI breakers.

Comment: The way the OP worded the question, it is a local requirement on new panels to have AFCI/GFCI breakers.  Seems like OP does not have the choice.  OP already has GFCI receptacles.

Comment: @crip659 OP is probably wrong, unless the circuits are new. We should correct wrong impressions.  Even if a locality tried, it's not a Code requirement and the correct response would be "cite, please".

Comment: I do imagine if this is the requirement, it is for new house/new panel, and not a new panel in an older house with GFCI receptacles.